# What are different options to implement Single sign on for windows store apps?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, single-sign-on, windows-authentication, azure-active-directory

I am new to windows development. I am looking at implement single sign on for windows store app but not sure how and what are the industry best practices. I have seen something about Active Directory but nor sure what is it. So kindly help me by specifying different options to implement Single sign on for windows store apps.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the authentication features in `Azure Mobile Apps`, it lets you have a different providers like: Google, Facebook, Twitter, Microsoft Account and Active Directory... etc.
And you set your API Keys from one place (Azure Portal) which make it very easy and useful even for cross-platform apps.

You could take a look here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/mobile/

Hopefully this is what you are looking for...

Comment: That gives an overall idea but my application is a windows store application which will be specific to one organization i.e. there will be a set of users with logins from the same organization but they might have different privileges. In this case what would be the best SSO option? Is it only Active Directory?? Please help @Nasser

Comment: Mobile Apps is flexible and easy to implement, you could link it to your Org's AAD, and provide this option only.. you can read more about the auth here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-authentication-overview/.